# RingOut failing to initiate first leg of call

Tags: phone-call, ringcentral, ringout

While trying to make a call using the RingCentral Platform RingOut API resource, the API responds with 200 and the message says "In Progress", but the call never actually happens. While trying to make sure it wasn't my code, I tested making a RingOut call using the RingCentral Soft Phone, and had the same problem.

- I have activated my account and set my user's password
- This is a US-based number
- I have created my application in the [Developer Portal](https://developers.ringcentral.com) and granted `RingOut` in the API Permissions for the app respectively
- I can successfully obtain an `access_token` from the Sandbox API https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com
- The token I receive is valid and `RingOut` is included as part of the `scope`

Here is the API Request I am sending to the Sandbox RingOut API:

```
POST /restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/ringout HTTP/1.1
Host: platform.devtest.ringcentral.com
Authorization: Bearer {{MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}}
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
    "from": {
        "phoneNumber":"{{MY_MAIN_COMPANY_NUMBER}}"
    },
    "to": {
            "phoneNumber":"{{MY_MOBILE_NUMBER}}"
    }
}
```

This fails in the [RingCentral API Explorer](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-explorer) as well, so I know it is not my code. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the RingCentral Soft Phone is configured to operate with the Sandbox APIs. Read **Configure Dev Environment** in the [Getting Started Guide](https://developers.ringcentral.com/library/getting-started.html) to learn how to setup your Soft Phone to use the Sandbox APIs.

Once you know the Soft Phone is configured for the correct environment (Sandbox or Production), the most common reason this happens is RingCentral User you authenticated with which does not have a **Direct Number** or **Digital Line** configured.

The first step to resolving this blocker depends upon your RingCentral Account type...

### For paid RingCentral Customer Accounts

Contact your RingCentral Account Administrator and ask them to add a **Digital Line** to the Sandbox Account User used while obtaining your `access_token`. You can also switch the credentials to a sandbox account user who already has a **Direct Number** or **Digital Line** configured on their account.

**-OR-**

You can use the steps below (if you have an administrator role assigned to your user in RingCentral).

### For Free RingCentral Developer Accounts

A. Login to your [Sandbox RingCentral Account](https://service.devtest.ringcentral.com), and then [Add a Digital Line on your User](https://success.ringcentral.com/articles/RC_Knowledge_Article/5-10-Adding-Phone-Numbers)

Note: A digital line is just adding a phone that is set to be a "Desktop Soft Phone".

**-OR**

B. If you have access to administrate your [Sandbox RingCentral Account](https://service.devtest.ringcentral.com), and then [Add a Direct Number on your User](https://success.ringcentral.com/articles/RC_Knowledge_Article/5-10-Adding-Extension-Direct-Numbers-via-Web)

The second step to resolving this blocker depends upon how you are attempting to make the RingOut, using the API or using the Soft Phone.

### Using the Soft Phone

Once you modify the user to have a **Digital Line**, re-authenticate to the RingCentral Soft Phone, and you should be able to make a call immediately.

### Using the [RingOut API](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefMakeRingOut)

Modify the body in your POST request to the [RingOut API to Make a Call](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefMakeRingOut) and set the `from.phoneNumber` to equal the new **Digital Line** phone number you received. Then you should be able to make your call using RingOut via the API (provided you do not receive any other errors).

```
POST /restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/ringout HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer {{YOUR_VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN_WITH_RINGOUT_SCOPE}}
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

{
    "from": {"phoneNumber": "{{REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_NEW_DIGITAL_LINE_PHONE_NUMBER}}"},
    "to": {"phoneNumber": "{{CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER}}"}
}
```